# text vs innerHTML in JQuery

Tags: jquery, text, innerhtml

I get the same result from both methods, but not sure why. Research on SO tells me this:

.text() returns JUST the text of that element and all of its descendant elements, where as .innerHTML returns all of the HTML in that element.

however, further research tells me this:
The real issue is that text() and innerHTML operate on completely different objects.

Can I get some clarification?

HTML

```
<table id="table2">
<th> Col1 </th>
<th> Col2 </th>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="data">456</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var x=$(this).text();
    alert(x); //returns '456'
})

var abc = document.getElementById('data');
var xyz = abc.innerHTML;
    alert(xyz); //also returns '456'
```

Comment: Yes, .text is a method of a jQuery collection, while .innerHTML is a method of html nodes. Two completely different things. One is implemented by the browser, the other is implemented by jQuery. They each also have differing purposes.

Comment: add some element to the cell, and you'll see the difference

Answer (score 6):

`.text()` will return a string representation of all the text nodes in that element while `.html()` will give you the presentation of all nodes.